# Google Cloud Natural Language API Usage - Analyze HTML Sentiment

Tags: python, nlp, google-cloud-platform

I want to use the Google Natural API to analyse news content given its html address, using one of the functions in the API, my code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import language
def sentiment(HTML):
    client=language.Client()
    document=client.document_from_html(HTML)
    sent_analysis=document.analyze_sentiment()
    senti = sent_analysis.sentiment
    print ('Score',senti.score,'Magnitude',senti.magnitude)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    senti=sentiment('http://www.marketwatch.com/story/amazon-adding-1000-full-time-jobs-with-michigan-fulfillment-center-2017-09-14?siteid=yhoof2&yptr=yahoo')
```

The result is always 0, whatever news page I pass in, it does not seem to do anything. Is there something wrong in how I use it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually classifying is the URL, not its content. The `HTML` content type means it will strip away any formatting present in the text, so if you have something like:

```
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
```

it will remove all the html tags.

To classify the contents of an article, you need to fetch it first, something like:

```
import requests
req = requests.get('http://www.marketwatch.com/story/amazon-adding-1000-full-time-jobs-with-michigan-fulfillment-center-2017-09-14?siteid=yhoof2&yptr=yahoo')
html = req.text
```

Now this will get the whole html file, which contains all kinds of other nonsense apart from the article, like the `<head>`. I'm not sure how good the language api is at removing that.